# How can I locate my panels using LayoutManager in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a little problem with my GUI task.

[This is the result I should achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOKqC.png)

[image]

[And this is what I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVTvE.png).

Can someone please tell me how to change my code, in order to locate my 3 panels correctly?

On the second picture, you can see my `JFrame` class.

Comment: Update your question and post your code as code formatted text.  We can't modify and test an image in our IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I would, starting from the 'inside out'<sup>1</sup>, do it like this:

[image]

1. By 'inside out' I mean: Starting from the smallest identifiable *group* of components in the GUI, layout them out on a single panel. Do the same with any other groups of components or controls the GUI has. Then in a step-by-step process, work outwards to larger areas, layout those small panels into ever-larger panels (with potentially different layouts & appropriate layout constraints).

Answer (score 1):

Using only `BorderLayout`, this is what your component structure could look like:

- main

  - blue + red: `BorderLayout.CENTER`

    - buttons + red: `BorderLayout.NORTH`

      - buttons: `BorderLayout.WEST` and `BorderLayout.EAST`
      - red: `BorderLayout.CENTER`
    - blue: `BorderLayout.CENTER`
  - green + buttons: `BorderLayout.EAST`

    - buttons: `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH`
    - green: `BorderLayout.CENTER`

In code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel buttonsAndRed = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
buttonsAndRed.add(new JButton("links"), BorderLayout.WEST);
buttonsAndRed.add(new JButton("rechts"), BorderLayout.EAST);
JPanel red = new JPanel();
red.setBackground(Color.RED);
buttonsAndRed.add(red, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel blue = new JPanel();
blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

JPanel blueAndRed = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
blueAndRed.add(buttonsAndRed, BorderLayout.NORTH);
blueAndRed.add(blue, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel buttonsAndGreen = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
buttonsAndGreen.add(new JButton("oben"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
buttonsAndGreen.add(new JButton("unten"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JPanel green = new JPanel();
green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
buttonsAndGreen.add(green, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.add(blueAndRed, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(buttonsAndGreen, BorderLayout.EAST);

frame.pack();
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```